# getting error when I build ngx-admin starter kit

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install, ngx-admin

when I download ngx-admin-starter-kit and build with `npm i` it builds successfully then I remove node_modules and again `npm i` then I get error below

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: tslint-language-service@0.9.9
npm ERR! Found: tslint@6.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/tslint
npm ERR!   dev tslint@"~6.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer tslint@"^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0" from codelyzer@6.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/codelyzer
npm ERR!     dev codelyzer@"^6.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer tslint@">= 4 < 6" from tslint-language-service@0.9.9
npm ERR! node_modules/tslint-language-service
npm ERR!   dev tslint-language-service@"^0.9.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: tslint@5.20.1
npm ERR! node_modules/tslint
npm ERR!   peer tslint@">= 4 < 6" from tslint-language-service@0.9.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/tslint-language-service
npm ERR!     dev tslint-language-service@"^0.9.9" from the root project
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\cihad\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cihad\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-31T09_59_42_148Z-debug-0.log
PS D:\Projects\ngx-admin-car>
PS D:\Projects\ngx-admin-car>
PS D:\Projects\ngx-admin-car> npm i
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: tslint-language-service@0.9.9
npm ERR! Found: tslint@6.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/tslint
npm ERR!   dev tslint@"~6.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer tslint@"^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0" from codelyzer@6.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/codelyzer
npm ERR!     dev codelyzer@"^6.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer tslint@">= 4 < 6" from tslint-language-service@0.9.9
npm ERR! node_modules/tslint-language-service
npm ERR!   dev tslint-language-service@"^0.9.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: tslint@5.20.1
npm ERR! node_modules/tslint
npm ERR!   peer tslint@">= 4 < 6" from tslint-language-service@0.9.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/tslint-language-service
npm ERR!     dev tslint-language-service@"^0.9.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\cihad\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cihad\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-31T10_00_15_506Z-debug-0.log
```

my `ng v` result

```
Angular CLI: 14.0.4
Node: 16.16.0
Package Manager: npm 8.13.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: <error>
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1400.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            14.0.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.0.4 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                    14.0.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             14.0.4 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.6.7 (cli-only)
typescript                      4.7.4 (cli-only)
```

Answer (score 0):

try running `npm install --force`